# How to append row to table id="address" on click of button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to append row to table `id="address"` on click of button

```
 <tr>
     <td>address:</td>
     <td><input type="text"></input></td>
     <td><input type="text"></input></td>
     <td><input type="text"></input></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: where u want to append?? `<table id="address">` on click of some button. right??

Answer (score 8):

```
$('#new_row').click(function() {
    $('table#address').append('<tr><td>columns</td></tr');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope you just want to add  a new row to the table with id "address". Following example should help you to accomplish this

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addRow(content,morecontent)
{
         if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return;
         tabBody=document.getElementsByTagName("TBODY").item(0);
         row=document.createElement("TR");
         cell1 = document.createElement("TD");
         cell2 = document.createElement("TD");
         textnode1=document.createTextNode(content);
         textnode2=document.createTextNode(morecontent);
         cell1.appendChild(textnode1);
         cell2.appendChild(textnode2);
         row.appendChild(cell1);
         row.appendChild(cell2);
         tabBody.appendChild(row);


}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border='1' id='mytable'>
<tbody>
<tr><td>22</td><td>333</td></tr>
<tr><td>22</td><td>333</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button onClick='addRow("123","456");return false;'>
Add Row</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, just thought of supporting him in his need.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$('table#address tr').append('<td>your new row</td>');
```

Comment: did u understand what OP wants??

Comment: Adding a new cell to an existing row certainly won't add a new row.

Comment: sorry guys :D then, $('table#address').append('<tr><td>address:</td><td><input type="text"></input></td><td><input type="text"></input></td><td><input type="text"></input></td></tr>');

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".ButtonId").click(function(){
$("table#address tr").append("<td>New Table Row</td>");
});
```

Make sure you refer your button and table with proper id

Answer (score 1):

you can also try with :

```
$("#buttonID").live('click',function(){
$("<td>New Row</td>").appendTo("table#address tr")
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KEL3M/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply giving the ID also work.

```
$('#address').append('<tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td><td>col3</td><td>col4</td> </tr>')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also make the table with that row and use `display: none` in the CSS, then make it show with a function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#yourbutton').click(function() {
        toggleRows();
    });
});

function toggleRows() {
    if ($('.colapsablerow').is(":visible")) {
        $('.colapsablerow').hide();
    } else {
        $('.colapsablerow').show();
    }
}
```

Using a class for the colapsable rows also allows to hide many rows at the same time.